# Check if on Custom Post Type for TinyMCE buttons

Tags: plugin-development

I'm adding TinyMCE buttons to my plugin and they're working, but I only want these buttons to show up for a certain custom post type. I followed this tutorial if it helps:

http://www.tutorialchip.com/wordpress/wordpress-shortcode-tinymce-button-tutorial-part-2/

How can I have that check if they are editing/posting a post in a custom post type of lets say, `newpages`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you followed that tutorial you linked then look at the function that registers the buttons:

```
function mylink_button() {
   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages'){
     return;
   }
   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true' ) {
     add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin' );
     add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'register_button' );
   }
}
```

and you change it a  bit to check for the post type:

```
function mylink_button() {
        if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages')){
         return;
        }
        if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true' ) {
            global $typenow;
            if (empty($typenow) && !empty($_GET['post'])) {
                $post = get_post($_GET['post']);
                $typenow = $post->post_type;
            }
            if ("newpages" == $typenow){
                add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin' );
                add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'register_button' );
            }
       }
    }
```

this way you only register the buttons on your "newpages" type

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Bainternet. Very useful. I used your solution with one small modification.

Instead of

```
global $typenow;
```

I took

```
global $current_screen;
$current_screen->post_type;
```

$typenow only returns the correct type, if you are inserting a new post. When you are editing an existing post, it always returns "post". So it's better to use $current_screen->post_type.